# ¿Como agrego botones de manera dinamica en tablas? (C#)

Tags: c#, datatable

Quiero agregar 3 botones en una sola columna de un **DataGridView** y no se como realizarlo de la forma correcta, ya puedo generar de manera dinamica la columna que yo deseo

Codigo Para generar Columna en blanco.

```
   DataGridViewColumn acciones = new DataGridViewColumn();
  acciones.CellTemplate = dataTabla.Columns[0].CellTemplate;
   acciones.AutoSizeMode = dataTabla.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode;
   acciones.HeaderText = "Acciones";
   acciones.Name = "ColAcciones";
   dataTabla.Columns.Add(acciones);
```

Codigo para generar el boton dentro de la columna. (No funciona)

```
Button btnEliminar = new Button();
           btnEliminar.Text = "Eliminar";


           foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataTabla.Rows)
           {
               row.Cells["ColAcciones"].Value = btnEliminar;
           }
```

la columna sigue creandose sin nada en su interior.

Ya intente hacerlo con ColumnButton, pero no quiero un solo boton por columna, quiero tres en una misma columna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "ID"; 
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Nombre";
    dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Precio";

    string[] row = new string[] { "1", "Producto 1", "1000" };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

    DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(btn);
    btn.Text = "Boton";
    btn.Name = "btnBoton";
    btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
}
```